# Do any of the big SSD makers make internal SSDs for the MacBook Pro?

Tags: ssd, apple, macbook

Do any of the big SSD makers, like Western Digital, make internal SSDs for the pre-TouchBar (pre-2106) MacBook Pro? These SSDs use m.2 PCIe interfaces but apparently they are modified in a way to make them exclusive to Apple. If not, which brand(s) do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Any NVMe drive should work from a hardware point of view (many youtube videos shows the process of backuping MacOS to it via external connection (USB), then pulling user data from your current install).

Examples are : Samsung's 970 and 980 (non Pro and Pro).

Comment: But these still need adapters. The idea of using an adapter on your primary disk is a bit troubling. Related or not, I've read that the computer may have trouble going to sleep.

Comment: The adapter is already in the machine according to tutorials..